# How to make a single form that works with an individual, and organisation and their Relationship in Wordpress

Tags: profile, webform-civicrm

Most of the Memberships for my organisation reside with Organisations which are then represented by a named individual.

Is it possible using CiviCRM in Wordpress to design a website form which collects the Individual data such as first name & last name AND Organisation data such as Organisation Name and then ties the two together by setting the Relationship as Employer<-->Employee.

There seem to be some solutions available for Drupal users such as Webform Integration or CiviRelate.

Any ideas on how one might do this in wordpress?

Comment: Hi Phil. Have you already set your Membership page up so that it is 'on behalf of' ie so the Membership is created for the Org, and the Individual becomes permissioned 'current employee of' that Org?

Comment: Hi Peter,   That works for me in WP.  You could add this as an answer and I'd upvote it.

Comment: You might also want to check the gravity forms integration (it is a paid plugin) from http://shop.civivip.com

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might need to set your Membership page up so that it is 'on behalf of' ie so the Membership is created for the Org, and the Individual becomes permissioned 'current employee of' that Org.
The 'on behalf of, settings are on the Contribution 'Title' tab. The profile it offers by default is a 'reserved' Profile (so is on the Reserved 'tab' on Profiles), but you can clone it, change the clone and use that if you don't like what the default one offers by way of fields.

Comment: Hi i've tried to add Individual First Name or Individual Last Name Fields to the On Behalf of Organisation Profile but it fails saying... "Cannot add or update profile field type Individual with combination of Household or Organization". Is there something else i need to do ?

Comment: Phil, the Organisation Profile is for the Organisation data. You also have a place on the Profiles tab of the Contribution page you set the Profile you want for First Last etc eg the New Individual Profile. Make sense?

Comment: So are you saying that my Wordpress page needs both an Individual Profile and an On behalf of Organisation Profile - Ok i'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: yes that would be the case

Comment: I tried this and My Wordpress page will only display the first CiviCRM profile included on it, the second is not displayed. Have you come across this issue before?